# Staying on the correct page after login

Tags: support, bug

I am repeatedly faced with the same problem:

- Go on a page (not logged in),
- Click "Add a comment",
- A pop-up appears,
- Click on "Sign up using Stack Exchange",
- "Sigh… I mixed "sign up" and "log in" once again",
- Click on "Log in",
- Log in,
- "I am logged in, but, this is not the page where I wanted to leave a comment, this is the front page !"

I'm not sure this can be easily corrected, but I guess that on the page
https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=…
the link on "sign up" ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/signup ) should just be modified as https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/signup?returnurl=…

A reason why I always make that confusion: at https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/login, it is written "Log in" then "Sign up", whereas the pop-up that appears says "Sign up or log in" (i.e. the opposite order).

[image: Steps to reproduce]

Edit: I think this question should be migrated to meta.sxe, and is not meta.tex.sxe specific.

Comment: Did you try with other browers?

Comment: Yep, same behaviour with Firefox or Chromium. Even if the link appears to be https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl…

Comment: Well, I thought it's some problem with the cache, but now... Unfortunately there is no other advice. Perhaps someone else encounters/encountered the same issue

Comment: Same problem with trying to log in to chat. Keep saying I have to log in, then I log in, then the loop repeats.

Comment: @AndrewCashner : I don't think this is the same problem. After the manipulation described, I *am* logged in, but not on the correct page. And, FYI, I always clear my cache and my cookies at the closing of my browser, so that cannot be the problem.